# Empty folders with mangled names being put in my user directory

Tags: macos

I have hundreds of empty folders with mangled names being put in my user folder. I have tried not showing hidden folders but I still have the problem. I can delete them and they come back on reboot. Running Sierra, and I just re-installed it this morning and still have the problem.

[image]

Comment: Why do the folders have such varied dates?

Comment: Any contents in these folders?

Comment: I wondered about the dates too. One more folder got added last night with no apps open.  They are all empty

Answer (score 2):

**That** is one of the strangest things I have ever seen and my introduction to Macintosh was with System 4 on a 512K Mac.

There could be a number of things causing that. A runaway/damaged process running in the background seems the most likely, but I suppose there could also be some disk corruption.

I would boot the system into recovery mode and run a repair on the startup volume using disk utility. If it finds no issue then it is more likely that it is a runaway/damaged process of some sort.

Booting into safe Mode (Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while starting up the Mac) will disable 3rd party applications that run at startup and if the problem goes away in safe mode it is something that was installed on the Mac that is now damaged. uninstalling the application, turning off any login items (system preferences > Users & Groups > [your user] > login items) and looking for other things that run at startup are a place to start.

If it is still happening it is likely an issue with macOS. In that case you could try downloading and installing the latest combo update, the latest for Sierra is [here.](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1931?locale=en_US)

Failing that I would reinstall macOS right over top of what you already have. While that *shouldn't* delete any data I would make sure you have a good backup first.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have tried everything you suggest and the problem still happens in safe mode. I installed Sierra this morning. I uninstalled every login item one at a time to check.

Comment: I'm going to back up to time machine then create a new user and dump everything into it.